# Does file descriptor remain valid for as long as the FILE* is not closed?

Tags: c

If I create/open a file and then call `fileno` on the `FILE*`:

```
int fd;
FILE* pF = fopen(file_path, "atb+");
if(pF)
{
    fd = fileno(pF);

    //....
}
```

Can I safely use my `fd` for as long as the `pF` is not `fclose`d?

Comment: yes, you can. Why would it change?

Comment: @Barmar: I'm just confirming. Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: This would be the most likely place for such documentation:  https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05  Good luck parsing that word salad to determine if it actually meets your needs.

Comment: Think of it logically. If it could spontaneously become invalid, what good is it?

Comment: @Barmar: There are, theoretically, ways something could become invalid other than spontaneously, such as by certain actions of the program, so that thinking does not resolve the question.

Comment: It would probably be better to say the FD is valid as long as the FILE is valid. If there's an error with the FILE, that could close the underlying fd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file descriptor will remain "valid" until it is closed.  It will be closed by a call to `fclose` or `freopen` on the original `FILE *`, but could also be closed by an explicit call to `close` by anyone.

Here "valid" just means that it will be usable for calls, and that those calls will refer to whatever underlying resource the file descriptor refers to.  If that resource becomes unavailable somehow (refers to a socket that has been shutdown or suffered a reset, refers to a file on a filesystem that has been unmounted, various other possibilities), those calls may fail and the resource might not be recoverable.

Note that `fileno` (and file descriptors in general) are not part of the C standard, but are part of [the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/)  The interactions between stdio and file descriptors are in [section 2.5 of the system interfaces](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05)

Comment: *The file descriptor will remain "valid" until it is closed.*  Note a file descriptor can also be closed if the `FD_CLOEXEC` flag is set on the file descriptor.  While user-defined `FILE *` streams will be nuked by the `exec...()` call that closes the descriptor, that flag being set might still affect `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` in the new process and leave them with invalid file descriptors and cause some, umm, *interesting* issues.

Comment: Just think of the bugs you can send downstream by doing that to someone else's process.  

Answer (score 1):

> Does file descriptor remain valid for as long as the FILE* is not closed?

Yes, with the restriction that you can't/shouldn't mix `FILE*` operations in between using fd operations.

> Can I safely use my fd for as long as the pF is not fclosed?

Yes.

> Is it documented anywhere?

Good luck reading https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05_01 .

Comment: Caveat: I find no guarantee that works when freopen() is called.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but just to use plain system calls, like `write(2)` or `close(2)`.  But you will be interferring the writes you do with the buffering system employed in the `fwrite/fread`, `printf`, `scanf`, `fgets` and all functions in the `stdio.h` package.  As stdio is not aware of the system calls you are making in the outside, it cannot (and will not) generally work as you expect it to do.